# Tour de Flex Source

Tags: apache-flex

I like Tour de Flex very much. I would like to build an application looking similar to Tour de Flex.

How can I get the source code of Tour de Flex (just UI code, no backend stuff)?

Comment: The source (including the CSS etc) is visible in the bottom pane. What else do you need?

Comment: Please don't address questions directly to specific users, even if they ask you to.  http://www.jamesward.com/2009/08/12/ask-the-ria-cowboy/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps sending an e-mail instead of posting it on a website would be a good start? :P

I guess a better place to ask this would be on the [Adobe Flex forums](http://www.adobe.com/go/flex_forums)

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Tour de Flex is not publicly available. However that application is pretty basic.  Just some skinning of a Flex application and a few Flex containers.

Answer (score 0):

The source code for Tour De Flex was donated to Apache and can now be found in the [Apache Flex utilities github site](https://github.com/apache/flex-utilities/tree/develop/TourDeFlex).